# FragmentPagerAdapter removing fragments on app resume

Tags: android, android-viewpager, adapter, empty-list

I have `android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter` which hosts about 1-10 fragments varying according to situation.
Each fragment has a `GridView` defined in its View.

[image]

If user puts app into background, starts another app, and comes back to my app. On some devices fragments are simply removed and app results in a  blank empty screen.  I tried changing to `FragmentPagerAdapter` but results in a crash situation. It throws `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed error.`

I can't understand the confusion around the system, as fragments are contained inside the activity, only created activity can delegate the call of notifying fragments.

Update 1:

From debugging this further, app is seem to throw IllegalStateException

when in FragmentPagerAdapater:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(SourceFile:1358)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(SourceFile:595)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitAllowingStateLoss(SourceFile:578)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(SourceFile:139)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(SourceFile:415)

When in FragmentStatePagerAdapter

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragement no longer exists for key f1: index 1
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getFragment(SourceFile:564)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.getItem(SourceFile:211)
                                                            restoreState
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(SourceFile:428)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is your current code around adding those fragments?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm late, but it seems like that if you are using a `FragmentPagerAdapter` it is not recreated after the activity is destroyed, and it tries to reference the old destroyed instance of activity. This is possible for example if you declare that adapter as `static`. Try to change your code in such a way that the adapter is always recreated on each activity creation.